# Proof for a subset of any finite set is finite

Tags: proof-verification, cardinals

Can anyone please tell me if my proof is fine?

Let N be a finite set. Then N = {n1,n2,....nk} has k elements. 
Let A be a subset of N and A does not equal N. 
Then A will either be empty or A will have less than k elements.
If A is empty then A has no elements, consequently A is finite.
If A has less than k elements, then k is finite so any number less than k is finite.
Then this implies A is finite.
Since A is any arbitrary subset of N, this implies all subsets of N will be finite.

Comment: What's your definition of a finite set?

Comment: A set A is finite if it has the same cardinality as {1,2,....,n} for some positive integer n.

Comment: And cardinality is defined by bijective maps, right? So, you should prove the statement by using such maps.

Comment: Would this work if I use aforementioned definition or do I need to tweak it a little?

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: But a bijection would not be possible between N and A as A has less elements than N. Should I show that any mapping from A to N would be injective and not surjective which will imply that elements in A are less than elements in N, which would then imply that A has finitely many elements?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's correct but it would be a lot easier to say: Let $|N|=k$, and $A\subset N$, that is $|A|\leq |N|<k<\infty$. However, it depends on what you're allowed to use to prove the statement.

Comment: Thank you!! This is more concise so I'll go with this